# Does scanf() take '\n' as input leftover from previous scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf

In the following C code:

```
char name[20];
int a;
int b;

for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("\nEnter name, a & b: ");
    scanf("%s %d %d",name,&a,&b);
}
```

does `scanf` read in the `'\n'` entered at the end of `scanf()` in 1st iteration, for the 2nd iteration inputs?

Comment: Why don't you try running this code through a debugger and see what happens. Then if it's unexpected or unclear post a question on that aspect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf` leaves the input stream pointing to the `\n`. In your case it doesn't make a difference: each time it's called, `scanf` will move along until it finds the next non-whitespace character. So giving it 10 lines of `name, a, b` as input will work as you expect.

But consider this:

```
scanf("%d", &a);
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
```

`fgets` reads until it finds the first newline character, so `str` will just get a value of `\n`, and `fgets` will *not* read the next line of input.