# fgets()'s first instance is being skipped

Tags: c, input, fgets

So I'm practicing c and am getting this this bug when I use fgets(). The first instance of the code gets skipped and goes to the next line.

CODE

```
for(g = 0;g<numStudents;g++)
  {
    array->firstName = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);
    array->lastName = malloc(sizeof(char)*BUFSIZE);

    printf("Student %d\n", g+1);
    printf("First Name:");
    fgets(array->firstName, BUFSIZE, stdin);
    printf("Last Name:");
    fgets(array->lastName, BUFSIZE, stdin);
    printf("\n\n");
  }
```

I am using scanf() before this section, so I found out that I have to flush the buffer. However that is not working.

The output would usually be:

```
Student 0
First Name:Last Name:(Cursor)
```

Comment: `sizeof(char) == 1` and is mandatory, can you please post your input? Also using `malloc()` for a fixed size is not really necessary.

Comment: At the very least, the answer to [Does `scanf()` take `'\n'` as input left over from previous `scanf()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1815986/does-scanf-take-n-as-input-leftover-from-previous-scanf) applies to your situation.  The `scanf()` probably leaves a newline in the input stream which `fgets()` reads as the first input 'line'.  I would close this as a duplicate, but I'd rather have some consensus before wielding Mjolnir.

Comment: How are you flushing the buffer after `scanf`?

Comment: Use `while((int c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);` before the loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to be careful mixing different input methods like `scanf` and `fgets`. If you `scanf("%d")` and enter a single integer followed by a newline, the pointer will be left at the newline (the first character not valid for constructing an integer), so *that's* what a following `fgets` will pick up, as you can see.

For example, consider the following small program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void) {
    int val;
    char buffer[100];
    scanf ("%d", &val);
    fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    printf ("%d[%s]\n", val, buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile/run that, then enter `123 456`, the output you'll see is:

```
123[ 456
]
```

There you can see that the `fgets` has picked up the rest of the line after the scanned integer, from the first non-digit space to the newline at the end.

If you use `scanf` alone, it's usually okay since *most* (but not quite all) format specifiers will skip leading whitespace before they read their item.

There are also ways to allow mixing of the different input methods, such as reading characters after the `scanf` until you get a newline, effectively throwing away the rest of the line (including the newline character).

But perhaps the easiest way is to use a custom-made, proven *line-input* function to get lines, and then `sscanf` the lines to get what you want, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

That way, *all* input is line-based and you still get the power of `scanf` to extract data from the line.